# Firefox addon SDK and DOM manipulation problems

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to get to grips with the **Firefox addon SDK** (previously known as Jetpack from what I understand), but I'm having problems working with the DOM.

I need to iterate over all of the text nodes in the DOM when a web page loads and make changes to some of the strings that they contain. I've posted a simplified version of what I'm doing below (new to Javascript, so forgive me any oddities).

```
    // test.js

    function parseElement(Element)
    {
      if (Element == null)
        return;

      var i = 0;
      var Result = false;

      if (Element.hasChildNodes)
      {
        var children = Element.childNodes;
        while (i <= children.length - 1)
        {
          var child = children.item(i);
          parseElement(child);
          i++;
        }
      }

      if (Element.nodeType == 3)
      {
        // For testing - see what the text node contains
        alert(Element.nodeValue);
        Result = true;
      }

      return Result;
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", function load(event)
    {
      window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
      parseElement(document.body); 
    }
```

When I create a basic HTML document:

```
    <!-- test.html -->

    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <b>hello world</b>
        <p>foo</p>
        <i>test</i>
      </body>
    </html>
```

...include this Javascript file in the HEAD section then open it in Firefox, the "alert" displays 6 dialog boxes containing:

```
    1) "hello world"
    2) blank -> no visible characters, just a newline
    3) "foo"
    4) blank -> no visible characters, just a newline
    5) "test"
    6) blank -> no visible characters, just a newline
```

Exactly what I would expect to see.

The problem arises when I create an addon and use test.js as a **page-mod Content Script** from my *main.js* file (modified to remove the "addEventListener" part). When I use "cfx run" to start Firefox with my addon installed, then open the same HTML document (with the "script" part for the test.js file commented), **the alerts do not display at all**.

So that's the first puzzle. But having also navigated to other web pages - for example, a YouTube video page - **the alert DOES display several dialogs, but they include very strange strings**, mostly the content of *script* tags:

EDIT I don't have enough reputation to embed an image, so here's a link instead showing the sort of thing I mean instead: http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/5994/mtpd.jpg

And again, *the text I would expect to see* is absent.

Apologies for some of the redundancy below, but just to be clear: this is my main.js:

```
    main.js

    var data = require("sdk/self").data;
    var data = require("sdk/self").data;

    exports.main = function()
    {
      pageMod.PageMod({
        include: "*",
        contentScriptFile: [data.url("test.js")]
      });
    }
```

And the modified version of the Javascript file is identical to the "test.js" listing above, but for the end part:

```
    test.js

    <snip>
      ...
      return Result;
    }

    parseElement(document.body);
```

I've included my project files (if I can call them that) in a zip if it makes things easier to visualise: http://www.mediafire.com/?774iprbngtlgkcp

I've tried changing

```
    parseElement(document.body);
```

to

```
    parseElement(unsafeWindow.document.body);
```

in case it makes any difference, but the outcome is identical.

So I'm very puzzled about what's happening. I can't understand why the test.js file isn't picking out the text nodes (and only the text nodes) from the DOM when I use it as part of an addon, but does exactly what I would anticipate when included as a script in a HTML document. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors in your lib code and contentScripts are usually logged to the Error Console. Check what is printed there. Also see the SDK console module.

Your page-mod won't run because by default page-mods will run only after the load event.
See the [`contentScriptWhen`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html#PageMod%28options%29) documentation.

script tags actually often have a text-node child containing the inline script source. So it is absolutely normal that those are enumerated as well.

For some discussion about walking tree nodes, see: [getElementsByTagName() equivalent for textNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes)
However, if you're after the text of specific ids/classes, consider using [`document.querySelector/.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), or if you're after nodes that have a specific XPath, use [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate). This very likely will be a lot faster.

Other than that, I cannot really tell what exactly your remaining issues are and what you're trying to achieve in the first place exactly, so I cannot advice on that.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your reply. My response is a bit belated because I wanted to do some more experimentation before following this up.

First, with regards to the problem I was having where none of the text nodes in my test HTML file were being enumerated - I've discovered that my add-on is NOT executed when a document is accessed via File->Open File.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is by design, but it seems an unlikely oversight. When I uploaded the test file to my host and accessed it from there, the text nodes were displayed as expected.

Comment: Second, I've found that the reason the text values I was expecting to find on YouTube video pages were "jumbled together" is that the first instances of those values are stored inside of JSON responses within the DOM (from what I can tell).

In addition, the visible occurrences of these text values were missing because of the "AJAX" nature of the page - my node enumeration was taking place before those values had been added to the page, so it was missing them. Now I watch for document changes and re-run the enumeration when a change is detected.

Comment: I've had awful problems with my JQuery AJAX requests. This StackOverflow question gave me some hints (I might ask a new question about this):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973643/error-in-jsonp-call-only-from-firefox-extension

There are a number of issues, and I'm not entirely happy with my solution. To begin with, I can't allow JQuery to handle the callback automatically for me because its reference to "window" is not the "real" window, and the callback fails.

Comment: So I set my own callback by specifying jsonpCallback, and adding a unsafeWindow.callback = function(data){ <do something>} function to my document.

That's fine except... I lose my reference to "this", which is the element I want to update in the web page. Further, I ALWAYS get an error, :success never fires, but :error ALWAYS fires. :complete fires, though. This is where it gets complicated.

Comment: My custom callback passes a parameter "data" which INCLUDES the full server response - but an error is still raised. :error seems to wipe out this response, so I can't access it in :complete (which fires later).

So what I do is, store the response "data" in my custom callback in a global variable, then access this in :complete - which also allows me to reference "this", the element on the page that I want to update with the details supplied by the remote server.

It's very messy, it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: Incidentally, I can't "thank" you with points because I don't have enough "reputation", but I appreciate your reply

Comment: OK, I think I've done that correctly now! I hope so anyway - all the best

Answer (score 1):

You wondered that

> I've discovered that my add-on is NOT executed when a document is
>   accessed via File->Open File.

That is by design. At [match-pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern), it says that

> A single asterisk matches any URL with an http, https, or ftp scheme.
>   For other schemes like file, resource, or data, use a scheme followed
>   by an asterisk, as below.

You can use the regular expression `/.*/` to match all sites and all schemas.

Comment: Thank you - I still need to come back to this and finish that portion of my project, so this is very useful to know.